# OS X menubar/dashboard/dock utility for monitoring a server?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, utilities, internet, webserver

Is there any desktop utility for OS X that would periodically monitor a (non-osx) server and display a status icon?  Something as simple as attempting to visit a URL every 5 minutes and turning red if it does not respond would be enough, although anything more detailed is interesting too.

Comment: Do you only intend to ever be watching 1 site? And *all* you want to know is reachable or not?

Comment: Also: What medium are you monitoring? Is ping enough? Are you checking accessibility of a website? SSH?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [GeekTool](http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/geektool/) (free)

GeekTool will let you set up a simple icon or show more detailed information, embedded in or floating over your desktop, based on whatever programming you want.

If you can write a script to check the server and return either a binary status or more detailed information, GeekTool is the way to display it.

Comment: That does the trick, esp. since I can set it always on top and then place it on top of the menu bar.

Answer (score 2):

### [ServerSiren](http://foggynoggin.com/serversiren) ($15 with 10 day free trial)

> With Server Siren, server downtime is a thing of the past. It runs as a menu bar item, so a quick glance is all it takes to see that everything is A-OK. If a server goes down, Server Siren alerts you immediately so you can fix the problem and get your site up and running again.

Comment: Unfortunately this one doesn't work with OS X >= 10.5 (I'm on Snow Leopard)